# Why is the HTTP verb POST called POST?

Tags: http, rest, post

The other verbs all make sense to me, but I don't have much context for "post" as a verb. Is it like post as in Post Office (which makes some sense, although seems like a stretch) or post like post on a bulletin board (makes less sense to me)? Does anyone know who decided on "POST" and why it was selected?

Comment: Because GIVE didn't sound quite as catchy. *-ducks-*

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn as in "give it a ..."?

Comment: @JohnSheehan Well actually, it's a HTTP method, not a HTTP verb :-P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, "*post like post on a bulletin board*" comes pretty close to the answer, I guess. In the end, that's exactly one of those functionalities this method was designed for. `POST` is always meant to post stuff to some kind of 'factory' to be handled by it - otherwise you could just use `PUT`. Let's have a look at [RFC2616, Section 9.5](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt):

> The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept
>   the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the
>   resource    identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is
>   designed    to allow a uniform method to cover the following
>   functions:
>
> ```
>   - Annotation of existing resources;
>
>   - Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list,
>     or similar group of articles;
>
>   - Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a
>     form, to a data-handling process;
>
>   - Extending a database through an append operation.
> ```

Of course this is not the exact definition of why it is called `POST`, but I think this might give some clues about the idea behind it.

Maybe we could also have a look at some meanings of the word 'post' (http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Post, the 3rd definition) - according to that, post as a verb can mean

- To mail (a letter or package)
- To inform of the latest news
- To transfer (an item) to a ledger in bookkeeping
- To make the necessary entries in (a ledger)

And this is exactly what `POST` does (metaphorically). If you want to send en email, you let your email-provider handle it and then inform you about the state. And this is also the difference between `PUT` and `POST`: If the client is in charge of handling the resource, you use `PUT` (because you know what to put and where to put it).

So, theoretically, if you knew the IP-address of the person you want to send the email to, you wouldn't need your provider to find this stuff out for you. But now, you know *what* to put, but not exactly *where*. So in this case, you use `POST`. You 'inform the server of the latest news' and the server decides where to put it. So you can think of it as 'transfering an item' to a resource that's already present (like a thread in a forum or something) - you just want to append something.

I hope this makes any sense...

Comment: This is an awesome breakdown of why POST makes sense. I suppose unless Tim Berners-Lee wanders in this is about as definitive as it's going to get...

Comment: @KelseyInnis Always glad to help :) And I also hope that Mr. Berners-Lee wouldn't laugh too hard at me for this... :-P

Comment: For a moment I thought I was on english.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

The POST method is used to request that the origin server accept the entity enclosed in the request as a new subordinate of the resource identified by the Request-URI in the Request-Line. POST is designed to allow a uniform method to cover the following functions:

- Annotation of existing resources;
- Posting a message to a bulletin board, newsgroup, mailing list, or similar group of articles;
- Providing a block of data, such as the result of submitting a form, to a data-handling process;
- Extending a database through an append operation.

[W3 / POST](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html)

REST asks developers to use HTTP methods explicitly and in a way that's consistent with the protocol definition. This basic REST design principle establishes a one-to-one mapping between create, read, update, and delete (CRUD) operations and HTTP methods. According to this mapping:

- To create a resource on the server, use POST.
- To retrieve a resource, use GET.
- To change the state of a resource or to update it, use PUT.
- To remove or delete a resource, use DELETE.

[IBM / REST](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful/)

When we are POSTing, we really are sending new data (creating resource) but not going to get it or calling about updates or asking for shredding our older documnets.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that post as in 'to post a letter' is much of a stretch. A POST request is a message containing data after all. As to the who, the verbs come from HTTP, so the origins would be the Html spec written by Tim Berners-Lee in 1995.